# How do you make a sunburst brushed metal effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

How do you make a sun brushed metal effect like in the image below? I've tried motion blurring a noise layer but this gives to much blur.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Draw a circle and apply a Radial Gradient to it. I simply used a Layer Style, but you can use a Gradient Layer if you want.

[image]

Use a custom gradient with several color stops. Use the **same color** for the stop furthest to the left and furthest to the right. Otherwise the gradient will show a "seam".

Then create  anew layer, fill it with black and add a **Mask** the size of the circle.

[image]

**Unlink the mask** with the layer, by clicking the chain icon between them:

[image]

Click the layer thumbnail so it's highlighted and choose `Filter > Stylize > Add Noise`, play with settings until you get a middle-ground and then click `OK`.

[image]

Then choose `Filter > Blur > Radial Blur`

[image]

lastly set the **Blend Mode** of the blurred layer to `Screen`:

[image]

You can then further refine the gradient:

[image]

And adjust opacities to blend things a bit better:

[image]

Comment: I know you are trying to replicate the user's example, but using a "zoom" pattern has little sense because this kind of brushed metal is done by spinning it, so a spin blur would be more realistic. :o)

Comment: @Rafael Your'e correct, and actually.. I'd use both.

Comment: Excellent example. Thanks, I used this today in my work.

Answer (score 2):

Acceptably finely brushed metal, even if blackened, has so fine scratches that computer screen probably cannot show them except with high zoom. But together the scratches and the light result a visible gradient effect. Thus I would start with a simplest possible conical gradient without adding any grain. Complex gradients can easily look out a folded rosette.

[image]

The gradient is 5 stop black-white-black-white-black. You can see some banding (=ray lines) due the limited accuracy.

8 bit deep colors create more rays when the brightness range is adjusted. Darkening is needed for an impression of black metal. A levels or curves adjustment layer is the simple solution:

[image]

For some internal math operation reasons the right adjustment was difficult, I didn't found a good setting.

But there's another option. Add a grey top layer and a black background. Adjust the opacities of the grey and gradient layers.

[image]

With different adjustments you get also brushed plain steel:

[image]

The gradient is opaque, so the black background is unnecessary.

With an adjustment layer you can make it glossy:

[image]